# Querying in Realm with Predicate crash if there is no table

Tags: ios, realm

If I use this code:

```
 NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", key, value];
 RLMArray *list = [cl objectsWithPredicate:pred];
```

It always throws exception: `'Invalid column name', reason: 'Column name objectId not found in table'`

Using `RLMArray *list = [cl allObjects];` is fine.

Is that Realm bug or I miss something

Comment: Does the `cl` class subclass `RLMObject`? Are you running this code very early in your app's lifecycle, i.e. at `+load` or `+initialize` time?

Comment: Yes, `cl` is a subclass of `RLMObject`. This code is run in the `viewDidLoad` of the `rootViewController` and the current Realm is empty.

Comment: Could you share more code? I can't reproduce your issue. I've reproduced your code in a test here and it works: https://gist.github.com/jpsim/6491a4206020cfb56808

Comment: I found the problem is the realm don't have a table for class `cl`. I should check if the realm have the table and then do query.

Comment: Realm should automatically create tables for RLMObject subclasses extremely early during your app's lifecycle. If this is not the case, then it's a bug that we would certainly like to fix. It shouldn't be necessary for you to check if the table has been created before attempting to use it. We'd appreciate any additional code, ideally if you could email a zip of your Xcode project, we could troubleshoot and fix the issue. Thanks! jp@realm.io

Comment: I found that it always happens with Realm which is created by `realmWithPath:` (I first call it in background thread, not in the main thread). And now, I am using Realm version 0.88

Answer (score 0):

I've found that Realm doesn't persist `readonly` properties. And as my class only had `readonly` properties (populated in the initializer) Realm would end up with a table that not only has no entries, but no columns as well.
The workaround is to simply re-declare all the properties as `readwrite` in the class extension.

I couldn't find this documented anywhere.